# Raise Package/ Class error for incompatible options

Tags: errors, package-writing, documentclass-writing, options, error-writing

When I am writing a package or class, I sometimes have some options that are incompatible with each other. What I want is to raise an error if two such options are imported at the same time. I tried `\@ifpackagewith{mypackage}{option1,option2}{<true>}{}`, but this still loads both options. Also, I would like it to work more "automatic" if possible. If I have 3 incompatible options, I want it to print a *different* message depending on which options where loaded.

Here is a MWE containing a `.sty` with two "incompatible" options: `option1` and `option2`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}

% Incompatible options:
\DeclareOption{option1}{\newcommand{\foo}{Foo baz baa}}
\DeclareOption{option2}{\newcommand{\foo}{Baa foo baz}}
% Unknown options:
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{mypackage}{No option ‘\CurrentOption’}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\makeatletter
\@ifpackagewith{mypackage}{option1,option2}{\PackageError{mypackage}{option clash: 'option1' and 'option2'}{Options are incompatible}}{}
\makeatother

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[option1,option2]{mypackage}

\begin{document}

This is a test.
\foo

\end{document}
```

I'm thinking that in case of incompatible options, neighter options should be used (but other options might still be used). Let's say I had a third option `option3` and tried `\usepackage[option1,option2,option3]{mypackage}`. Then the result should be the same as `\usepackage[option3]{mypackage}` (if `option3` is compatible with `option1` and `option2`) and an error.

If `option3` is also incompatible:

- when `option1` and `option3` is loaded, the error message should say that `option1` and `option3` is incompatible, and load neighther options.
- when `option1`, `option2` and `option3` is loaded, the error message should say that `option1`, `option2` and `option3` is incompatible and not load any of the three options.

In general I only want to print the options that *were actually loaded* in the error message. I also want the package to use non of the conflicting options, as mentioned above.

Comment: as your sentences show your requirements are contradictory. "when option1, option2 and option3 is loaded" then "not load any of the three options".  The options are loaded, you can choose to change their effects don't put `\newcommand{\foo}` directly in the option just set some flag and then at the end define or do not define `\foo` depending on which flags are set

Comment: better would be to not have conflicting options; instead of having foo1 foo2 and foo3 options where you can only use one, have an option with a value `foo=1`  and check the value is 1 2 or 3 (or red green or blue, or whatever values make sense)

Comment: For instance: I have an option to make some text (in the title) ragged left, ragged right or centered. It does not make sense to use these together, and I would like to output a warning if someone tries to use them together. Since I "don't know" what they mean, I want the conflicting options to be ignored.

Comment: why not have `title-align=left` (or right or center or error)

Comment: normally classes just use a "last wins" eg `\documentclass[10pt,11pt,12pt]{article}` is not an error, but the first two options are ignored

Comment: Is it possible to modify the "last wins" approach to instead do "no one wins"? Also, would still like to produce some sort of error or warning to notify users that they are not meant to use those options together.

Comment: as I say above you just need to test at the end,

Comment: So to summarize, using two defined options (for which the average user would expect the last to win, because that's how almost all packages work) is worse than using an undefined option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does (more or less) what @DavidCarlisle suggested. You can easily check if conflicting options were specified if their sum is greater than 1.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}

\newcommand\foo
  {\PackageError{mypackage}{No option setting \noexpand\foo specified}{}}

% Incompatible options:
\chardef\mypkg@optA=0
\chardef\mypkg@optB=0
\DeclareOption{option1}{\chardef\mypkg@optA=1\relax}
\DeclareOption{option2}{\chardef\mypkg@optB=1\relax}
% Unknown options:
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{mypackage}{No option ‘\CurrentOption’}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\ifnum\numexpr\mypkg@optA+\mypkg@optB>\@ne % easily extensible for n options
  \PackageError{mypackage}
    {The options `option1` and `option2` are mutually exclusive}
    {Sorry, but I decided that way}
\fi
\ifodd\mypkg@optA
  \renewcommand{\foo}{Foo baz baa}
\fi
\ifodd\mypkg@optB
  \renewcommand{\foo}{Baa foo baz}
\fi

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[option1,option2]{mypackage}

\begin{document}

This is a test.
\foo

\end{document}
```

---

The following implements a mechanism that should ease this madness (sorry, but I still think this is a bad design choice):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}

\newcommand\foo
  {\PackageError{mypackage}{No option setting \noexpand\foo specified}{}}

% Incompatible options:
\newcommand\mypkg@options@code{}
\newcommand\mypkg@DeclareOption[1]
  {\expandafter\mypkg@DeclareOption@\csname mypkg@opt@#1\endcsname{#1}}
\newcommand\mypkg@DeclareOption@[3]
  {%
    \chardef#1=\z@
    \DeclareOption{#2}{\chardef#1=\@ne}%
    \edef\mypkg@options@code
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter
          {%
            \mypkg@options@code
            \ifodd#1%
              \expandafter\@secondoftwo
            \fi
            \@gobble{#3}%
          }%
      }%
  }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \mypkg@map@clist \clist_map_function:nN
\cs_new_eq:NN \mypkg@use@clist \clist_use:nnnn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\mypkg@conflicting@options[1]
  {%
    \ifnum\numexpr\mypkg@map@clist{#1}\mypkg@conflicting@options@>\@ne
      \PackageError{mypackage}
        {%
          The following options are mutually exclusive:\MessageBreak
          \mypkg@use@clist{#1}{ and }{, }{ and }%
        }
        {Sorry, but I decided that way}%
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\mypkg@conflicting@options@[1]{+\csname mypkg@opt@#1\endcsname}

\mypkg@DeclareOption{option1}{\renewcommand{\foo}{Foo baz baa}}
\mypkg@DeclareOption{option2}{\renewcommand{\foo}{Baa foo baz}}
\mypkg@DeclareOption{option3}{\renewcommand{\foo}{Baz baa foo}}
% Unknown options:
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{mypackage}{No option ‘\CurrentOption’}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\mypkg@conflicting@options{option1,option2,option3}

% run the code of the options
\mypkg@options@code

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[option1]{mypackage}

\begin{document}

This is a test.
\foo

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I'm just wonderig if it is possible to customize the message in an easy way (without long and nested if statements)?

Comment: @Vebjorn see an edit for something that might be what you want. (Else, describe what you mean with "customize")